# membership test in pandas data frame column

Tags: python, list, pandas, contains, membership

I have a pandas data frame that one of its columns is a list. Please see below:

```
>>> a.head
    C1  C2
0   23  [2,4,5,8,1]
1   24  [1,2]
2   15  [-2]
3   19  [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

I would like to find a row that contains 6 in the C2 and return the value in C1. I thought for something like

```
b = a["C1"][(6 in a["C2"])]
return(int(b))
```

but it is not working. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `apply` and `in` for test value in `list` for creating `boolean mask`:

```
print (a.C2.apply(lambda x: 6 in x))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: C2, dtype: bool
```

Then use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for select by `mask`:

```
b = a.loc[a.C2.apply(lambda x: 6 in x), 'C1']
print (b)
3    19
Name: C1, dtype: int64
```

Last if need scalar output convert to `numpy array` and select first value by `[]`:

```
print (b.values)
[19]

print (b.values[0])
19
```

Or use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (b.iat[0])
19

print (b.iloc[0])
19
```

Comment: FWIW, apply is usually **way** slower than built-in methods that do the same thing.

Comment: @ringo - I agree, but here is tested column `C2` filled with lists, so `isin` failed, because `isin` working for test columns filled by scalars like `C1`.

Answer (score 3):

For a built-in **Pandas** method try `isin`.

**Pandas** columns, `Series` objects, have a [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) called `isin` that is purposed for this sort of thing. It returns a positional `boolean Series` (mask). It will find values in your column that are in a given list.

```
s = pd.Series(['lama', 'cow', 'lama', 'beetle', 'lama',
               'hippo'], name='animal')
s.isin(['cow', 'lama'])
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP is asking for. It's not how to test for a column's membership in a given list; it's how to test for a value's membership _in a list column_.